# How to cancel a Context Menu Opened Event?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I want to cancel the Context Menu Opened Event of a TreeViewItem

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

i thought this should work but instead i got a tiny context menu that has no menu items but i would like to have nothing appearing. 
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the `ContextMenuOpening` event of the control that owns the context menu, which is fired right before the context menu opens. There you can change the context menu or suppress it. Your code for the event to suppress works if you use the `Opening` event, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613568%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for further infos.

Comment: Gah! beat me by a mouse click! Just to clarify, this event is to be handled on the owner control. Example: this.ContextMenuOpening

Comment: In summary, set `e.handled = true;` in the `ContextMenuOpening` event handler.